# Vertically align images in PAGE

Tags: html, css

No JSFiddle or anything. Very simple question. I have 4 images, all of different sizes. I want them in a row, centered in the middle of the PAGE. NOT a div, a PAGE. I've found so many things online, and I don't know if I'm being n00by, or if this is just CSS being annoying as per usual, but they all seem to be about centering in a div. I want the images to be centered on the PAGE.

If there's no way of doing that, is there a way to make a div which automatically scales to the size of the native display window?

Thanks

Comment: There are 4 of them, as mentioned. One is 100x800, two are 150x150, and one is 150x340

Comment: Oh wait, in a row?! Dang it, my code will just overlap everything :(

Comment: @TheJuniorProgrammer I love CSS :p

Comment: I rush too much to answer questions...i'm a disgrace xD

Answer (score 0):

This code is flawless - works on any image size:

```
 img.yourimage (or img#yourimage){
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
     position:fixed;

     //does the magic - no need to know your image size
     transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 }
```

Comment: No... this doesn't move the image at all. Does the image have to be fixed?

Comment: Go ahead, just remember that what I posted is the wrong answer...you can use my answer, but I don't want rep for the wrong answer, makes me feel guilty...

Comment: i think this code will make all 4 images collapse into one as they will overlap each other, no ? As OP didnt mention his browser requirement, transform is > IE 9

Comment: @Andrew That's what I said above on Arcayn's post, I answered too quickly. Do you think I should remove my post??

Comment: @TheJuniorProgrammer sorry I didnt read the comment above lol, I go through too quickly, my bad